# How can I get MariaDB to pick up the system time zone?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am running a database server with `Ubuntu 14.04` and `MariaDB` version "`15.1 Distrib 10.0.21-MariaDB`".

I have set the system time zone to "`Australia/Canberra`" using "`dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`". The contents of `/etc/timezone` verifies this.

However, in `MariaDB`, the result of "show variables like `'%time_zone`'" is:

system_time_zone ====> UTC

time_zone  ======>       SYSTEM

I don't want to have to run `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` or set the `timezone` offset in `my.cnf` or `mariadb.cnf`. How can I get *MariaDB* to use the correct system `timezone`? I have already tried restarting the database with "service `mysql` restart".

Comment: I set my system timezone to Australia/Canberra and then I retarted the mysql service. MariaDB showed system_time_zone = AEDT. And indeed the NOW() function properly show the datetime from Australia/Canberra.  So, it should work.  Check your my.cnf for something like default_time_zone=UTC. That line might prevent MariaDB to take the timezone from the system.

Comment: Thanks, Ciprian. I have done and checked these things already, but I will try it again for good measure.